# Access highlighted item in AngularJS dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, mouseover

I'm generating a dropdown list like this:

```
<select ng-model="myModel.someName" ng-options="item.name as item.value for item in dropdownListOptions" ></select>
```

This works fine but now I'd like to be able to show some more information about each item in the list as the user moves up and down it, before they click on one to select it.

In other words I need to get the value of the currently highlighted option that the mouse is over without it being clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you can get with plain Javascript and you won't do better with Angular. There is no mouse over event for `option` elements of a drop down list.

The only way to achieve this is to have a custom drop down list made of HTML elements to which you will attach event handlers.
You can use [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) for example.